# Cannot read property 'getProduct'(action name) of undefined at Store._callee in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am working on a vue project where I am using vuex for managing state. I have defined state, actions, mutations as well as dispatch to call the action. But the problem is, I am getting an error near dispatch like Cannot read property 'getProduct'(action name) of undefined at Store._callee.

Can anyone guide me where I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

Dispatch action from component:

```
async created() {
  try {
     await this.$store.dispatch("getProduct");
  } catch (error) {
     console.log("Error", error);
  }
}
```

Actions code:

Here in ProductService, I have getProduct() function where I am performing API call.

```
const actions = {
   async getProduct({ commit }) {
      commit("GET_PRODUCT", await ProductService.getProduct());
   }
}
```

Mutation code:

```
const mutations = {
   GET_PRODUCT: (state, product) => {
      state.product = product;   // Here I am mutating the state
   }
}
```

Comment: At the top of your `getProduct` action could you put `console.log(ProductService)`, to confirm whether that gets called and whether `ProductService` is actually defined?

Comment: this is unrelated, but this is wrong commit("GET_PRODUCT", await ProductService.getProduct()); commits are sync operations. You need to wait and then commit const res = await ProductService.getProduct() commit("GET_PRODUCT", res)

Comment: @RaduDiță, If you can see official site, there is an example as -> actions: {
  async actionA ({ commit }) {
    commit('gotData', await getData())
  },
  async actionB ({ dispatch, commit }) {
    await dispatch('actionA') // wait for `actionA` to finish
    commit('gotOtherData', await getOtherData())
  }
}

Comment: You are right, my bad

Comment: @Dcoder What do you mean by *'working'*? Do you mean you've fixed the problem or do you mean that the logging I suggested is logging the expected object but the error remains?

Comment: @skirtle, sorry my bad, there was a typo mistake. I wanted to say that is not working. When I am trying to do console.log, nothing prints which means there is something wrong in that service file. But that service is defined.

Comment: I don't know which file you mean when you say *'that service file'*. Please could you check what you wrote in the original question because I suspect the bit where you wrote *'Here in ProductService'* isn't supposed to say that, or perhaps the code samples aren't as you intended? Either way, to be clear, I wanted you to put the logging at the top of the `getProduct` **action**, not the similarly named method in `ProductService`. If you aren't seeing that logging then the action isn't even being called.

Comment: 'that service file' means, ProductSerive.js is a file where I have written all the api calls related to product. I used it by importing like - import ProductService from "/path" and then I'm using getProduct() function in that ProductService as ProductService.getProduct()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging a long time, I got to know that there was an error in service function *'ProductService.getProduct()'* inside action code. Here in my case I have created service file named *'ProductService'* in which I have defined functions for API calls and *'getProduct()'* is one of the functions where API call is done to get list of products.

While I tried to print whether this function call is returning values or not and this was returning undefined and for that the above error was coming. Then I fixed issue in service function for which this function call returns undefined and after that it works fine.

Error was in below line of code.

```
commit("GET_PRODUCT", await ProductService.getProduct());
```

Thanks @skirtle and @Radu Diță for your comments.